# How to use Host Attribute with appSettings value

Tags: c#, routes

I am wanting to use the `Host()` attribute to help restrict API Endpoints that I cannot use [Authorize] on as they are for unauthenticated users, such as registration and password reset etc.

I currently have this setup

**appsettings.json**

```
...
"Cors": {
    "AllowedOrigins": "https://mydomain";"https://www.mydomain"
},
...
```

I bring this in using

```
services.Configure<AllowedDomains>(options =>
    config.GetSection($"Cors").Bind(options)); //config is IConfiguration
```

**AllowedDomains**

```
public class AllowedDomains
{
    public string AllowedOrigins { get; set; }
    public string[] AllowedHosts
    {
        get{
            return AllowedOrigins.Split(";");
        }
    }
}
```

And then in my controller

```
private readonly AllowedDomains allowedDomains;
public Controller(IOptions<AllowedDomains> allowedDomains)
{
    this.allowedDomains = allowedDomains.Value;
}
```

but when I try to use the attribute like this

```
[Host(allowedDomains.AllowedHosts)]
```

I get the error `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Controller.allowedDomains'`

I managed to get the AllowedHosts to be static (ignoring the not being able to add static classes in the services configure method) but got the error `An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type`

I could just do `[Host(new string[]{"mydomain","www.mydomain","localhost"})]` but I wanted it to be dynamic out of the appsettings 1) so I don't have to have it written multiple times, and 2) so I only include localhost in the local version but I just don't know where to go next

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done by using the `Host()` attribute, nor making a custom attribute inheriting from `IHostMetaData`.

You have to make your own custom attribute starting from fresh with inheriting the base `Attribute` class.

Once working this out, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67845762/7147233) which creates this attribute, using `IAuthorizationFilter` but because I wanted to have my hosts dynamically, as said in the answer, I need to inject `IConfiguration` which I used the `GetService()` method, found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58012764/7147233).

But because I had the full URL in my appsettings for CORS purposes, but this Allowed hosts wants just the domain, I added a second field in my appsettings to have just the domain, (I felt this was better than looping through the URLs to get just the domains from within the attribute.

And then one last change, was changing the return result to be an unauthorised error instead of just a badrequest.

So my final code looks like this,

```
public class AllowedDomainAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public IEnumerable<string> AllowedHosts { get; set; }
    public AllowedDomainAttribute()
    {
    }
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var config = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IConfiguration>();
        AllowedHosts = config.GetSection("Cors")
            .GetValue<string>("AllowedDomains")
            .Split(";")
            .Select(o => o.TrimEnd('/'))
            .ToArray();
        //  Get host from the request and check if it's in the enumeration of allowed hosts
        string host = context.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host;
        if (!AllowedHosts.Contains(host, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            //  Request came from an unauthorised host, return unauthorised
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```